# Secure Rest Service in AppEngine

Tags: java, spring, rest, google-app-engine

I am developing a rest service using spring framework. I deployed it to google cloud app-engine and It worked. Now I am trying to make my rest service. What is the best way to secure a restAPI deployed in google cloud app-engine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Security along with JWT authentication to secure your Rest Endpoints.